# How correct use bitmask class?

Tags: php, class, bit-manipulation

I trying to use this class which i found here on SO:

```
 <?php
            class bitmask
            {               
                public $permissions = array(
                                            "read" => false,
                                            "write" => false,
                                            "delete" => false,
                                            "change_permissions" => false,
                                            "admin" => false,                                   
                                            "seller" => false,
                                            "superAdmin" => false
                                            );
        
               
                public function getPermissions($bitMask = 0)
                {
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($this->permissions as $key => $value)
                    {
                        $this->permissions[$key] = (($bitMask & pow(2, $i)) != 0) ? true : false;
        
                        // Uncomment the next line if you would like to see what is happening.
                        //echo $key . " i= ".strval($i)." power=" . strval(pow(2,$i)). "bitwise & = " . strval($bitMask & pow(2,$i))."<br>";
                        $i++;
                    }
                    return $this->permissions;
                }
        
              
                function toBitmask()
                {
                    $bitmask = 0;
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($this->permissions as $key => $value)
                    {
                        if ($value)
                        {
                            $bitmask += pow(2, $i);
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                    
                    return $bitmask;
                }
            }
        ?>
        
         require ("class_bitmask.php");
           if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
                    $bm = new bitmask();      
                  
                    $bm->$permissions["Interface"] = isset($_POST["Interface"]);
                    $bm->$permissions["Presence"] = isset($_POST["Presence"]);
                    $bm->$permissions["Disponent"] = isset($_POST["Disponent"]);
                    $bm->$permissions["Buchhalter"] = isset($_POST["Buchhalter"]);
                    $bm->$permissions["seller"] = isset($_POST["seller"]);
                    $bm->$permissions["TankAdministrator"] = isset($_POST["TankAdministrator"]);
                    $bm->$permissions["admin"] = isset($_POST["admin"]);
                    $bm->$permissions['superAdmin'] = isset($_POST['superAdmin']);          
                    
                  $rights = $bm->toBitmask();
                    echo $rights;
     <form method="post" action="">
       <div>
            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="name here">
            <input type="checkbox" name="superAdmin" checked> superAdmin<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Admin" checked> Admin<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Seller" checked>Seller<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Disponent"  checked>Dispatcher<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Buchhalter" checked>no-name<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="TankAdministrator" checked>no-name<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Presence" checked>no-name<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Interface" checked>no-name<br> 
       </div>
            
            <button  id="save_btn"> register</button>
        </form>
```

It always print 0, why?
Please help

- This array is used to represent the users permission in usable format.
  *
  * You can change remove or add values to suit your needs.
  * Just ensure that each element defaults to false. Once you have started storing
  * users permsisions a change to the order of this array will cause the
  * permissions to be incorectly interpreted.

Comment: `$bm->$permissions` should be `$bm->permissions`.

Comment: Thank You, I spend 2hour searching error...