# DRY principle in check user rights, how to avoid repeat of code on every page?

Tags: php, session, access-rights

I must develop website which have pages with different access levels. Already have `users` table in db and for first page which requre rigths check has made this code, work nice

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        $bitmask = $row['Rights'];
        $bm = new bitmask();
        $permarr = $bm->getPermissions($bitmask);
        if (!($permarr["admin"] || $permarr['superAdmin'])){
            $home_url = '../auth-login.php';
            header("Location: $home_url");
            echo 'access denied';
            exit();
        }
```

pseudocode:

1. start sess
2. select rights from DB where `user = $SESS[user]`
3. check selection result rights with actual required rights

It is possible to avoiding same code with only changes `REQUIRED_RIGHTS` on every page? How to make possible include this with some variable parameters USER, `REQUIRED_RIGHTS` in PHP?

Comment: I see you are using `$permarr["admin"]` for example as a specified roll. Is the way you have set up your access rolls still open for change or should we consider this fixed?

Comment: My bitmask class have 8 roles, stored in DB as BYTE.Adding more roles not possible only this 8 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66788824/how-correct-use-bitmask-class

Comment: @RakeshKumarOad: thanks for wanting to edit questions here. A bit of feedback: it's worth noting that code formatting is fine on its own, it does not need to be made bold as well. Also, programming languages, libraries, software, etc are not themselves code, so they don't need to be rendered in preformatting.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Actum Ne Agas:*** *"Do Not Do A Thing Already Done!"*

It sounds to me like you're about to set out "creating a web-site entirely from scratch."  Why not, instead, evaluate the very many **frameworks** that have been developed for PHP, and base your new site on one of them?

Frameworks provide robust solutions for many common problems, such as this one.  (They each tend to do it in different ways.)

Comment: Altho I agree with your answer, it does not strictly answer the question. We might want to assert that the approach is a given. Maybe it would be interesting to list the different ways these frameworks tackle this problem, or at least some considerations when trying to design a system. But I fear this interpretation of the question is too broad however. Just a way to keep the code DRY should be sufficient.